# SSL Wildcard Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, wildcard

I have a SAAS in which I need to create multiple subdomains dynamically (Note: There are a lot of subdomains,  I don't know which ones will be auto generated ). So I can´t repeat this for each one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a1.app.example.com
    Redirect / https://a1.app.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to redirect each one of the subdomains in http to https?. Something like  " Redirect / https://*.app.example.com   "

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.example.com
    Redirect / https://*.app.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.example.com
    ServerAlias *.app.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxxxxx

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xxxxx.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xxxx.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/xxxx.crt
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You didn't provide any input on the answer I provided. Gently reminding you to give some feedback / vote / accept if that helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add that to your main vhost:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,R=301]
```

And make sure `mod_rewrite` is active. You can activate it using the `a2enmod rewrite` command.